# SQL Server Linked Server not returning all results

Tags: sql-server, azure, linked-server, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

I'm trying to read data out of a from a linked server and the join is bringing back only the first match.  If I ran the query on the directly on the remote server I'd get multiple rows back.  Both the local and remote servers are Azure Managed Instances.  @@Version shows:

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May 15 2020 00:47:08   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
```

The query is as follows:

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 15;

SELECT 'LinkedServerMI lnkSvr w/join' fromSrc, *
FROM LinkedServer.DatabaseName.dbo.CustomerInfoPhone cip
   INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerInfo ci ON cip.CustomerInfoId = ci.CustomerInfoId -- Simple join
WHERE ci.CustomerInfoId = @Id; -- No other filters
-- One row comes back, expected 2 or more

SELECT 'LinkedServerMI lnkSvr select only' fromSrc, *
FROM LinkedServer.DatabaseName.dbo.CustomerInfoPhone cip
WHERE cip.CustomerInfoId = @Id;
--For the customer id in question 2 rows come back.
```

The Linked Server is created like so:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LinkedServer', @srvproduct=N'SQL', @provider=N'MSOLEDBSQL', @datasrc=N'<servername>', @provstr=N'Data Source=<servername>;User ID=<remoteuser>;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LinkedServer',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser='<remoteuser>',@rmtpassword='########';
```

Query plan was to big to share.  This link should allow you to see the file hosted on Google: [Linked Server Query Plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W4xhSbAMzPlvb73y6y-9FGHgBgjqa4vW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try changing your INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN. If you get multiple rows back, you may have a data integrity issue between your CustomerInfoId columns.

Comment: Run linked server select only query next to `CustomerInfo ` select only query for the same ID, see how many results you get from both queries.

Comment: LEFT JOIN still brought back only 1 result.  RIGHT JOIN brought back all results.  Switching the base table, order that the tables appear in the query brought back all results.

Comment: Selecting against CustomerInfo brought back the expected 1 row/result set.